# Linux menuconfig failed

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

When I configure linux, I come across the following error:

```
[linux-devkit]:/opt/ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-03.00.00.04/board-support/linux-4.4.12+gitAUTOINC+3639bea54a-g3639bea54a> make menuconfig
HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/mconf.o
In file included from /opt/ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-03.00.00.04/linux-devkit/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/features.h:389:0,
             from /opt/ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-03.00.00.04/linux-devkit/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/ctype.h:25,
             from scripts/kconfig/mconf.c:11:
/opt/ti-processor-sdk-linux-am335x-evm-03.00.00.04/linux-devkit/sysroots/cortexa8hf-neon-linux-gnueabi/usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:29: fatal error: gnu/stubs-soft.h: No such file or directory
```

It seems that some package fails to be installed, however, after I search for the Internet for a whole day, I could not get a satisfying answer, could anyone offer me help? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You are trying to build your own kernel, unless you really know what you're doing it is a cumbersome path. I'd recommend to download ready made kernels if you really need one with specific options. FWIW: I believe that you need to have look into what "ti-processor-sdk-linux" has as dependencies (what it requires to be able to compile).